# Integrating multipart middlware to express application

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data

I need to receive, in a single request, either *JSON data* and files. So I've been using `body-parser` which works perfect. However I'm having problems finding a module working nice with express.

This is my router setup:

```
router.post('/',
  // controllers.requireAuthorization,
  controllers.multipartMiddleware,
  function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    return res.json({ body: req.body });
  },
  controllers.sitters.validate,
  controllers.sitters.create,
  controllers.sitters.serialize
);
```

This is what my multipart middleare function looks like, as you can see I'm using multiparty:

```
function multipartMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if (req.get('Content-Type').indexOf('multipart/form-data') + 1) {
    new multiparty.Form().parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
      req.body = fields;
      return next(err);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(req.get('Content-Type'));
    return next();
  }
}
```

Of course I've added that premature response return for debug purposes. So I need:

- Receives files which will be streamed right away to S3.
- Parse the rest of data as normal data.
- Correctly get the data parsed

The issues are seeing right now:

- It takes long sometimes even for small files (less than 512k, up to 5 seconds, this could be becase I'm using vagrant while developing but I think it's odd).
- Fields are not parsed properly:

[image: enter code here]

See how the value of `loca` is inside a wrapping array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would checkout [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), its a popular Express middleware and has a number of different ways to handle files (one or many). It also still allows for fields to be set which will come through on your `req.body`.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer.dest({ 'temp/' });

// looking for single file, named 'file'
app.put('/file', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  // access the file
  var file = req.file

  // any form fields sent in addition to the file are here
  var body = req.body; 
});
```

Another popular package thats an alternative to `multer` is [`busboy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy). Its also worth noting that `multer` is written on top of `busboy`.